# PHP solo almacene patente, km y fecha, pero que no pueda ingresar km menor al anterior

Tags: php

Desarrollé un programa para ingresar patentes, km y fecha. Quisiera que solo aceptara mayúsculas y números, sin guiones. El problema es que cuando ingreso una patente con minúscula me aparece el aviso de "reintente ingresa patente", pero la información se almacena igualmente, y necesito que no se almacene si esta en minúsculas. Al igual que necesito que no almacene km menores al anterior ingresado.

Si coloco la consulta después de mi primer if tengo error por no tener definidas las otras variables.

Este es el programa que he realizado hasta ahora

CÓDIGO

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['Patente']) ==6){
        $Patente = trim($_POST['Patente']);
        $Patente = strtoupper($Patente);
        if (preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]*$/", $Patente)) {
        ?>
            <h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado la Patente correctamente</h3>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar correctamente la Patente</h3>
        <?php
        }
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['Km']) >=1) {
        $Km = trim($_POST['Km']);
        $sentencia = "SELECT*FROM Km WHERE Km <= $Km";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);
        $existe = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($existe >= 0) {
        ?>
            <h3 class="bad">El Km ingresado es menor o igual al anterior</h3>
        <?php
        }
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $Km)); {
        ?>
            <h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado el Km correctamente</h3>
        <?php
        }
    } else {
    ?>
        <h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar Km</h3>
    <?php
    }

    $Fecha_reg=date("y/m/d");
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO km(Patente, Km, Fecha_reg) VALUES ('$Patente','$Km','$Fecha_reg')";
    $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if ($resultado) {
    ?>
        <h3 class="ok">Información Almacenada</h3>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <h3 class="bad">Ha ocurrido un error</h3>
    <?php
    }
} else {
?>
    <h3 class="bad">Complete correctamente la información</h3>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿y donde está la consulta que te lo hace?  Si no está dentro de ese condicional seguramente la hará igualmente, que es lo que te está pasando ¿no crees?

Comment: No entiendo porque has aceptado una respuesta que no ha tenido en cuenta los números, **tal como indicas en el título**, y lo único que hace, como todas las respuestas que te han dado, es pasarlo todo a mayúsculas, pero no verifican si tiene caracteres especiales ni nada, por lo tanto te pueden poner guiones, asteriscos, etc.  En tu pregunta tu código ya era correcto, y tan solo debías mover la consulta dentro del primer if, pero como no has puesto donde ejecutas la consulta no se te podia responder concretamente y de forma certera.

Comment: Acabo de darte una respuesta completa, mira a ver si te funciona tal cual y comentamos los problemas que te de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de validar si esta en muysculas o minusculas

Podrias convertir todo el campo a mayusculas

```
strtoupper — Convierte un string a mayúsculas
```

Ejemplo

```
<?php
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtoupper($str);
echo $str; // muestra: MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB AND SHE LOVED IT SO
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto y más abajo lo explico:

```
<?php

// inicializamos una variable que nos irá recogiendo todos los mensajes 
$msg = '';

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // validación patente
    if (strlen($_POST['Patente']) == 6){
        $Patente = trim($_POST['Patente']);
        $Patente = strtoupper($Patente);
        if (preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]*$/", $Patente)) {
            $msg .= '<h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado la Patente correctamente</h3>';
            $comprobacion_patente = true;
        } else {
            $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar correctamente la Patente</h3>';
            $comprobacion_patente = false;
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">El total de caracteres permitido para una patente son 6. Reintente ingresar correctamente la Patente</h3>';
        $comprobacion_patente = false;
    }

    // validación km
    // primero evaluamos si la patente era buena, sino no hace falta seguir aún
    if ($comprobacion_patente == true) {
        if (strlen($_POST['Km']) >=1) {
            $Km = trim($_POST['Km']);
            $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM Km WHERE Patente = '$Patente' AND Km >= $Km";
            $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);
            $existe = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if ($existe > 0) {
                $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">El Km ingresado es menor o igual al anterior</h3>';
                $comprobacion_km = false;
            } else {
                if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $Km)) {
                    $msg .= '<h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado el Km correctamente</h3>';
                    $comprobacion_km = true;
                } else {
                    $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">El km, no es un número válido!</h3>';
                    $comprobacion_km = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar Km</h3>';
            $comprobacion_km = false;
        }
    }

    // evaluamos si debe o no insertarse el registro
    if ($comprobacion_km == true and $comprobacion_km == true) {
        $Fecha_reg = date("y/m/d");
        // comprobamos la fecha
        $sentencia2 = "SELECT * FROM Km WHERE Patente = '$Patente' AND Fecha_reg = '$Fecha_reg'";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia2);
        $existe2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

        if ($existe2 == 0) {
            $msg .= '<h3 class="ok">Fecha correcta</h3>';
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO km(`Patente`, `Km`, `Fecha_reg`) VALUES ('$Patente','$Km','$Fecha_reg')";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
            if ($resultado) {
                $msg .= '<h3 class="ok">Información Almacenada</h3>';
            } else {
                $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">Ha ocurrido un error</h3>';
            }
        } else {
            $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">La fecha no se puede repetir. Ya existe un registro con esta fecha.</h3>';
        }
    }
} else {
    $msg .= '<h3 class="bad">Complete correctamente la información</h3>';
}
// escupimos todos los mensajes acumulados a la salida
echo $msg;
```

Los cambios realizados han sido muchos, pero a grandes trechos son:

1. Se ha creado una variable `$msg` que va a ir almacenando los diversos mensajes de verificación, error o éxito de las distintas comprobaciones e inserciones, en lugar de mezclar constantemente código PHP con la salida, la cual, desde mi punto de vista, siempre debe ser al final.
2. Se han estructurado mejor los bloques de validaciones y usando nuevas variables denominadas `comprobacion_xxxx` se han ido guardando sus resultados para su uso posterior en el momento de calcular si hay que realizar o no la inserción de los datos
3. Se han modificado las consultas SQL para tener en cuenta más valores, incorporando el de Patente en las claúsulas WHERE, pues de otro modo el resultado no se correspondia con lo esperado y planteado en la pregunta y comentarios
4. Se ha agregado una consulta para comprobar también si la fecha es coincidente con algun registro anterior en la tabla y proceder adecuadamente en cada caso
5. Todo lo demás han sido errores menores, tanto de comprensión como de código, que se han ido corrigiendo sobre la marcha

Comment: en este caso con las patentes y las fechas no hay problema, pero no se como hacer q no almacene km menor al que ya este ingresado por patente, es decir, que si una patente X ingreso un km el dia de ayer, hoy esa misma patente no pueda ingresar un Km menor al ingresado ayer.

Comment: mmm... perdona mi desconocimiento... ¿pero que es una patente? ¿y un km?  para mi una patente es algo que se registra para que los demas no lo puedan usar sin tu permiso.. y un km es un kilometro... pero me cuesta entender que relación tienen y quizás por eso no lo veo claro aún... unas preguntas más... ¿las patentes esas se pueden repetir en esa tabla?  ¿que estructura tiene?  ¿id (autoincremental), patente, km y fecha? ¿u otra?

Comment: y cuando dices `necesito que no almacene km menores al anterior ingresado` ¿a que te refieres?  ¿a una patente igual anterior o a la ultima patente registrada en la tabla aunque sea distinta?  (vale, no hace falta que respondas, me lo has dicho en tu primer comentario de este hilo)

Comment: Gracias por el interes en ayudarme, la patente es el numero asignado a un vehiculo y km son los kilometros recorridos total del vehiculo.
estas patentes no pueden ingresar mas de 1 vez al dia la informacion de su km, y el km no puede ser menor al del dia anterior.
en la tabla si se pueden repetir estas patentes, pero como te contaba, el usuario solo puede ingresar información 1 vez por patente al dia

Comment: ah, es una matricula entonces (o el número de bastidor o algo que lo identifica de forma única en tu localización), je.. okok... a ver como lo enfoco pues lo de la fecha no se está verificando tampoco en tu código... de momento voy a actualizar mi respuesta para lo de los km

Comment: Vale, ya lo he actualizado y también comprueba la fecha.  Mira a ver si ahora te funciona bien

Comment: Acabo de cambiar el condicional de los km, que lo tenias mal... ahora es `if ($existe > 0) {` (antes habias puesto `if ($existe >= 0) {` y era incorrecto, pues la comparación ya la haces en la propia consulta, y si te da resultado positivo entonces es que está mal, pero si te da 0 entonces es que está bien)

Comment: aun me almacena km inferiores al anterior según patente, y me entrega puros mensajes de que esta bien cuando no lo está

Comment: La fecha es un parámetro para tener en cuenta bajo ese condicional de `km`? Porque veo que la respuesta cumple según lo planteado. ¿Qué parámetros estás pasando?

Comment: Y también, depende del contexto que estamos hablando, ¿son `km` recorridos por día o son una acumulación de `km` como resultado del uso de un vehículo? ¿Por qué no podría ingresar menos `km` que el día de ayer? es decir que si hoy en mi vehículo anduve 10 km, mañana tengo que hacer 11, pasado mañana serían 12, y así sucesivamente? Para mi resulta un poco complicado cumplir la cuota en un caso real

Comment: hola, el km es una acumulación, por eso no puede ser menor al anterior.
la fecha cumple que no se puedan ingresar dos km de una misma patente por día, pero es el km el que no me cumple que no se puedan ingresar menores al ingreso anterior, ahora puede que el usuario no ingrese km todos los dias, por eso la idea es que no pueda ingresar km menor al anterior pero no necesariamente del dia anterior, sino del ultimo ingresado de esa patente

Comment: A ver, acerca de los mensajes, tan solo debes cambiarlos por los correctos... es decir, por ejemplo, donde dice `Se ha ingresado la Patente correctamente` quizás debas poner `El número de patente es correcto.` o no pongas nada hasta el final, eso ya es tu decisión. No me he fijado en lo que dicen realmente, pero siéntete libre de quitarlos o ponerlos como quieras, pues quizás ahora pierden un poco el sentido original, pero hazlo pensando que se van acumulando y deben tener sentido.

Comment: Y en cuanto a lo otro, acabo de corregirlo, vuelve a probar.

Comment: Perdón, aún quedaba un fallo... habias puesto un punto y coma en un condicional que lo bloqueaba al ponerle un else... actualiza de nuevo esta página para probar la última respuesta actualizada

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero aun se almacena km menores a los ingresado anteriormente por patente, ahora puede que el usuario no ingrese km todos los dias, por eso la idea es que no pueda ingresar km menor al anterior pero no necesariamente del dia anterior, sino del ultimo ingresado de esa patente

Comment: La consulta la tenias al reves: `SELECT * FROM Km WHERE Patente = '$Patente' AND Km <= $Km`.  Ya lo he corregido y ahora es: `SELECT * FROM Km WHERE Patente = '$Patente' AND Km >= $Km` pues nos interesa saber si hay algun registro de kilometro superior o igual al que vamos a poner, y no si existen registros anteriores con números menores de km

Comment: siii, no me habia dado cuenta, la dejare como  Km< $Km, para que tampoco se puedan ingresar iguales, muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: De todas formas lo mejor es hacer un count(*) en esa consulta, para no sobrecargar la memoria del servidor con datos innecesarios

Comment: Si esta respuesta cumple con lo esperado cambia la aceptación de la misma para que la comunidad lo sepa, sino no entenderan que hayas aceptado la otra

Comment: y no quites el igual... o quítalo y prueba, pero no creo que te funcione como esperas, creo que terminarás poniéndolo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141007/discussion-between-valentina-h-and-masterguru).

Comment: @ValentinaH Te he dejado la explicación del count(*) en el chat, ya te la mirarás

Comment: @ValentinaH y acabo de agregar una explicación genérica, sin ir al detalle, de todos los cambios realizados para que la respuesta sea completa.

Answer (score 1):

¿Estás usando un formulario web? Entonces otra opción es el atributo [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern):

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="Patente" pattern="[A-Z0-9]+" placeholder="Patente" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Hola @masterguru, replicando un poco a SO Inglés, me gusta dar respuestas alternativas, al problema o a las otras respuestas. Es algo veo recibido positivamente en SO. Por ejemplo, en SO hay preguntas de 2011 que hoy en día siguen recibiendo respuestas a medida que salen nuevos features de los lenguajes o a alguien se le ocurrió una mejor forma. Entonces mi respuesta para este caso: "¿Estas enredado/a con el backend?, que tal si lo resuelves en el frontend con una simple implementación"

Comment: Sí, te doy toda la razón, y me parece muy bien la respuesta como alternativa a su problema real. Ya te digo, mi fallo fue pensar que ninguna respuesta de las que vi habia tenido en cuenta mi comentario sobre la consulta con el insert a la base de datos que quedaba fuera de su condicional y no ví más allá en ese momento.  Suerte que lo he repasado y he podido enmendar el error. Gracias! :-)

Answer (score 0):

para comprobar si tiene letras minusculas puedes utilizar la función **ctype_upper**

```
$cadenas = array('PATITO', 'PaTITO', 'patito');
foreach ($cadenas as $palabra) {
    if (ctype_upper($palabra)) {
        echo "La palabra '$palabra' es buena.";
        echo "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "La palabra '$palabra' tiene minusculas.";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

esto re regresaría lo siguiente:

La palabra 'PATITO' es buena.

La palabra 'PaTITO' tiene minusculas.

La palabra 'patito' tiene minusculas.