# que no se puedan ingresar datos menores a los ya ingresados por variable

Tags: php, mysql

Realice una tabla en MySQL para la recolección de información desde php de km por patente diario, pero tengo problemas en la parte en que el usuario ingresa información, ya que necesito que no se registre en la base de datos un km menor al ya ingresado por patente.

Esto es lo que he intentado, aunque me genera la alerta de que el km ingresado es menor o igual al anterior, se me guarda igual la información en la base de datos.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

if(strlen($_POST['Patente']) ==6){
     $Patente = trim($_POST['Patente']);
     $Patente = strtoupper($Patente);
     if (preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]*$/",$Patente)) {
       ?>
       <h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado la Patente correctamente</h3>
       <?php
     }else {
       ?>
       <h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar correctamente la Patente</h3>
       <?php
     }
if (strlen($_POST['Km']) >=1) {
    $Km= trim($_POST['Km']);
    $sentencia="SELECT*FROM Km
           WHERE Km <= $Km";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
$existe= mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($existe>=0){
   ?>
   <h3 class="bad">El Km ingresado es menor o igual al anterior</h3>
   <?php
}
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$Km));{
     ?>
     <h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado el Km correctamente</h3>
     <?php
   }
   }else{
     ?>
     <h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar Km</h3>
     <?php

 }
     $Fecha_reg=date("y/m/d");
     $consulta = "INSERT INTO km(Patente, Km, Fecha_reg) VALUES ('$Patente','$Km','$Fecha_reg')";
     $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
     if ($resultado) {
       ?>
       <h3 class="ok">Información Almacenada</h3>
       <?php
     }else{
       ?>
       <h3 class="bad">Ha ocurrido un error</h3>
       <?php
     }
     }else {
       ?>
       <h3 class="bad">Complete correctamente la información</h3>
       <?php
     }
   }

?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [PHP solo almacene mayúsculas y números](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/569847/php-solo-almacene-may%c3%basculas-y-n%c3%bameros)

Comment: consulta, entonces dentro de mi consulta debo colocar las condiciones de almacenamiento?

Comment: En tu otra pregunta ya te pedí que pusieras lo que has puesto en esta, es decir, tus consultas a MySQL para indicartelo mejor. En cambio cogistes y como hicistes dos preguntas en una diste por válida una solución que te dejaba a medias.  Ahora has vuelto a duplicar la pregunta pero poniendo toda la información, eso esta mejor, pero al ser duplicada si te contesto en esta la otra quedará mal para siempre (mal respuesta y mal preguntada). Léete bien mis comentarios en la otra pregunta, sobretodo donde te digo **tan solo debías mover la consulta dentro del primer if,**.

Comment: Es decir, por un lado haces condicionales para mostrar los mensajes, pero obvias por completo poner las consultas al lado o no de esos mensajes, en la misma condición, y por lo tanto, aunque los mensajes sean correctos, después estas ejecutando la consulta sí o sí, pues no forman parte de la condición, sino que dejas las consultas para después, y siguiendo el curso del procedimiento, acaban ejecutándose siempre.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la consulta siempre se ejecuta, en tu caso, yo encapsularía la lógica para validar si los km son mayores o menores dentro de una función. Algo como esto:

```
// Declaración de la función
       function verifyQuery(){
        if ($existe>=0){
         ?>
         <h3 class="bad">El Km ingresado es menor o igual al anterior</h3>
         <?php
            return false;
         }
           else if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$Km));{
             ?>
             <h3 class="ok">Se ha ingresado el Km correctamente</h3>
             <?php 
              return true;
           }
           else{
             ?>
             <h3 class="bad">Reintente ingresar Km</h3>
             <?php 
              return false;
          }
         }

    // Invocación de la función
       if (verifyQuery()){
             $Fecha_reg=date("y/m/d");
             $consulta = "INSERT INTO km(Patente, Km, Fecha_reg) VALUES   ('$Patente','$Km','$Fecha_reg')";
             $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        }
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero es una pregunta duplicada y ya ha sido respondida ampliamente en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/571782/263200)